# Linked object is not verified while testing

Tags: java

I'm posting here and snap from Book "Java The complete reference". I tried to test the statement made in this snapshot. Result is 20 for both b1 and b2 which shows that objects are linked. But the book says Objects are not linked and any change to b1 should not affect, b2.

Where I am making mistake?

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
Box b1 = new Box();
b1.width = 10;
b1.height = 20;
b1.depth = 15;

Box b2 = b1;
double vol;
// assign values to mybox1's instance variables

/* assign different values to mybox2's
instance variables */
b1.width = 20;
b1.height = 299;
b1.depth = 15;

System.out.println(b1.width);
System.out.println(b2.width);
    }
```

[image]

Comment: Some people vote to close this as 'assistance to write or debug code' which IMHO isn't really the case. Only because OP adds a coding example doesn't necessarily make it a coding question. As far as I see it it's more about how references in Java work (which may or may not be off topic, not sure).

Answer (score 0):

No, the book does not claim that they are not linked - it says that `b1` and `b2` are referring o the same object.

It only states that *assignment* to one of them does not change the other in any way.

You are mutating the Object they both refer to.

Comment: you see the last line in the snap., if you change b1, it should not affect b2. then why once i have changed b1, b2 has changed too...? and book says that objects are not linked... you can read carefully in snap

Comment: No, the books clearly says that both are pointing to the same object. They are not linked in any *other* way, but if you *modify* the object they refer to through any of the two references, you'll see the changes through the other as well.

Comment: As the image shows, there is only one Object that has `width`, `height` and `depth`. The book just wants to make clear that changing one reference (i.e. assigning a different value to it - e.g. null, or a reference to some other box object) does not change the other reference in any way.

Comment: @Roker: my mum calls me "son", my friends call me "Jörg", my hairdresser calls me "Mr. Mittag". If my hairdresser cuts my hair, it doesn't matter what name you use to reference me, my hair is still cut. You won't see me with long hair, just because you refer to me by a different name.

Comment: Sorry @Jorg it's not just name, it has been clearly mentioned that if you change b1, b1 will change but b2 is still pointing to the original object, and original object has not changed...

Comment: @Roker exactly - the references `b1` and `b2` are just names - at the moment, they are used to refer to the same object. If you change any of them (the only way to change a refernce is to assign something new to it), it now refers to something different, but the other one is unchanged.